# Delete modules and variables that are not used in IAR

Tags: compiler, cmsis, iar

I wanted to use a standard library  (CMSIS-DSP) and I only used a few functions & variables of that library, but it's like the whole library has been added to my project.

And it takes a lot of memory, but now I have an error of lack of memory
This space is related to the common table in CMSIS-DSP
that used for calculating fft

And this is also the case, the IAR  compiler said that I will delete the module and the variables that are not used https://www.iar.com/knowledge/learn/programming/overriding-and-redirecting-library-modules-without-rebuilding-the-entire-library/, but this has not happened to me.

And as far as I understand, it is possible to define a series of rules or flags for the compiler to consider only the required parts for this library model, which are generally large, but we only need a small part of them.

Has anyone had such an experience that without changing the source of the library, just by making settings in the compiler, only the required parts have been used?
And how to define the flags and where should they be defined? On top of the source as defined? In Linker? or...

Comment: how do you know that the used part does not make use of the rest of the library?

Comment: @jsotola Well, I'm getting FFT so that the relevant library is designed in such a way that the necessary coefficients for calculating FFT are placed separately for each FFT size, that is, for example, the coefficients of a  FFT with a length of 32 are separate from the Fourier coefficients with a length of 256.